# WordPress FaceBook Plugin Error

Tags: wordpress, facebook

In order to work with facebook an article that was posted in wordpress,
I installed the facebook plugin to word press.

1. Obtain the App ID and App Secret in FaceBook, and was set to WordPress.
2. In FaceBook, I've set the AppDomains.
3. In FaceBook, Action in the setting of the Open Graph: Publish, Object Type: I have set the Article.
4. Tags, User Messages, it has been saved and put a check in Exlicitly Shared.

However, if *"3. Authenticate with Facebook to allow your Facebook application to post to your Timeline or Page on your behalf when a post is published X"* and become not, can not be set wordpress and Facebook of cooperation.

After: If you click the *"2.Associate an Open Graph action-object pair for your application people can publish an article"* link, it is an error page.

Do not know how to resolve?

**Facebook Plugin Version: 1.5.5**

Comment: use the support on the plugin download page?....if you need help with writing code or understanding a particular piece of code ask here.

Answer (score 0):

It is an error in the code .. it is no longer supported by Facebook .. but it will only tell you how to create the object(Article) and the action(publish)

Which can be done in very easy steps:

1. Go to your facebook developer page;
2. Select Open Graph from the left sidebar;
3. go to the Object Type Tab and press add new .. and write article on the pop-up
4. then go to action types, press add new and write publish

Et Voila,

But being not supported anymore .. you will need to change the coder coding ... as well if you wanna make it work